# Confusion about drawable sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I made this button:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkrMD.png

But the image is much bigger than it should be (it should be a quarter of its current size). I made various sizes of the image and put each into the respective drawable folder.

The size of the icon should be:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/12E8r.png

How do I scale the image down to the size I need to do be (as it is in the regular drawable size)?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3,056"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_arrow_up_b"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:padding="15dp"
    />
```

Comment: Looks like you are confused about pixels, dps and everything that follows.
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use a `Button` in this case. You should use a `ImageButton`. Maybe they work the same but if you are putting an image in a button, using `ImageButton` makes a lot of sense.

If you use an `ImageButton`, the image is always stretched to fit the size of the button. That means if you want to make the image smaller, you just make the button smaller.